# How do I extend the default CSS editor in Eclipse to add custom behavior for my Eclipse plugin?

Tags: css, eclipse, editor, eclipse-plugin

I'm looking to add custom tooltips and autocomplete to CSS files in Eclipse builds running our plugin, but I would prefer not redoing a lot of the work that went into the existing CSS editor in Eclipse. I understand the basics of using an extension point and creating a custom editor for a new filetype, but not where to start for the existing .css extension.

Does anyone know what the extension point would be for adding to the CSS editor?
How would I extend the Eclipse CSS Editor to add the functionality I want?
Would this even be possible?

Thanks in advance.